# DataSnap Web server working in FASTCGI, is it possible?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, datasnap

I created a DataSnap web server in Delphi that works as ISAPI in a IIS server. Some parts are not thread-safe and I would like to move FASTCGI. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the DataSnap server from the Wizard, the allowed kind of servers are displayed:

[image: DataSnap modes]

There is no direct FastCgi possibility.

The *Stand-Alone* server [has stability issues](https://robertocschneiders.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/datasnap-analysis-based-on-speed-stability-tests-part-2/), and Apache is not so well supported under Windows, so installing it as an ISAPI module is the best known solution...